# Returning 1 object/record from my model in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In a test app I running, I have fixture data for employees with name, department, etc.  Currently, my model contains all of the employees, and I am able to make an employee list. However, I want to make a side component that lists the information of 1 specific employee (i.e. the one clicked, as a tooltip).  How can I pass just 1 employee to my component?

I have an action that updates a property whenever someone clicks a name.  I thought to do a computed property to query the model based on that name, but I am not sure how to filter my model to return just the one employee.

```
actions: {
  updateProfile(person) {
    set(this, 'profile', person);
  }
}
```

And my computed property:

```
currentProfile: computed('profile', function(){
  return this.model.find('person', {'name': get(this, 'profile')});
}),
```

Is there a simple way to return just the 1 object I want from my model?

**Solution**

I needed to filter on `this` and not the model itself.  Then, I had to just return the firstObject, even though there was only 1 match (that was the main issue).

```
 currentProfile: computed('profile', function(){
    return this.filterBy('name', get(this, 'profile')).get('firstObject');
 }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
currentProfile: computed('profile', function(){
  var query = {'name': get(this, 'profile')};
  return this.model.find('person', query).then(function(people){
    return people.get('firstObject');
  });
})
```

Comment: I get `this.model.find is not a function` in my console.

Comment: Yeah, I was not on the right track.  But you are right with `get('firstObject')`.  I revised to:

    `currentProfile: computed('profile', function(){`
        `return this.filterBy('name', get(this, 'profile')).get('firstObject');`
      `}),`

Comment: I don't know how to do multi-lines in comments, but the key was to use filterBy, but I was never getting the firstObject, as you suggested.  This seems to work!  Thanks!